# Posting Camera Pictures to the server (django rest framework ) From Ionic

Tags: angularjs, django, http, ionic-framework, django-rest-framework

I am completely new to Ionic, AngularJS, and django-restframework, So in the course of building my first application i am experiencing these issues highlighted below.

1. I have the camera and file transfer plugin installed in my app
2. I implemented the camera function successfully, i installed the apk
   (debug release) after running ionic build  android, and it
    accesses the camera and takes the picture on the mobile device (Samsung) that it was installed on.
3. However, the problem i am facing is about posting the camera image to
   my back end (django-restframework), i suspect the "http POST" request is somehow being   transformed into a GET request which prevents the image from
   uploading ...because i get a reference to all objects contained in that database when i inspect with chrome which typically should be the case if i issue a simple get request as i am using DRF's modelviewset,  Please can anyone help me with this??

**app.js**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ngCordova'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form i
nputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();


       }
      });
    })
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$compileProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
     $stateProvider
      // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
        .state('app', {
        abstract:true,
        url: '/app',   
        templateUrl: 'templates/app.html'
      })

      .state('app.welcome', {
          url: '/welcome',    
          views: {
            'welcome': {
              templateUrl: 'templates/welcome.html',        
            }
          }
        })
      .state('app.news', {
          url: '/news',   
          views: {
            'welcome': {
              templateUrl: 'templates/news.html',
              controller: 'homeCtrl'
            }
          }
        })
      .state('app.vendor', {
          url: '/vendor',     
          views: {
            'welcome': {
              templateUrl: 'templates/vendor.html',
              controller: 'homeCtrl'
            }
          }
        })

      .state('app.map', {
          url: '/map',
          cache:false,
          views: {
            'welcome': {

          templateUrl: 'templates/map.html',
          controller: 'mapCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
  .state('app.report', {
    url: '/report',
    views: {
      'welcome': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/report.html',
        controller: 'ReportCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('app/welcome');

});
```

**controller.js**

```
    $scope.imagereport = {
     imagelist:[],
     addimage :function(){
        var nt = $scope.imagereport;
        $ionicActionSheet.show({
        buttons: [             
            { text: 'From Camera' },
            {text:'From Gallery'}
        ],

        titleText: 'Supporting Pictures',
        cancelText: 'Close',       
        buttonClicked: function(index) {
            if(index === 0) {       
            $scope.addimages(1);
            }
            else{
                $scope.addimages(2);
                }

        }

    });
    }
    };


$scope.addimages =function(eve) {   
$scope.imgo;          
  var options = {
     quality : 75,
      destinationType: 1,
     targetWidth: 200,
     targetHeight: 200,
     sourceType:eve,
     correctOrientation:true,
     saveToPhotoAlbum: false,

        encodingType: 0     // 0=JPG 1=PNG
  };

  Camera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {         
         var obj = imageData;   
         $scope.imagetaken.push(obj); 
         $scope.imgo =imageData;
         var opt = {
         fileKey : "file",
         fileName :fileURL.substr(imageData.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
         chunkedMode :false,
         mimeType : "image/jpeg", 
         headers :{ Connection:"close", 'CONTENT-TYPE':'application/json', Vary:'Accept' ,'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'x-requested-with' },
         //popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
         saveToPhotoAlbum: false        
        };
        var url = "http://riwama.sites.djangoeurope.com/addtemprorarypicapi"
       $cordovaFileTransfer.upload( encodeURI("http://riwama.sites.djangoeurope.com/addtemprorarypicapi"),imageData, opt).then(    
       function(result){
        console.log('Success: ' +JSON.stringify(result));       
        $.each(result,function(){
        $.each(this,function(k,v){
        var did = k;
        $scope.ids.push(did);
        });
        });
        var im = $scope.imagetaken;
        $scope.imagetaken.push(imageData);          
            },
         function(err){          
            alert('can not upload image because: ' +JSON.stringify(err));
            console.log(err)        
            },
            function (progress) {
            $timeout(function () {
          $scope.upProgress = (progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100;
           });
        });
      }, function(err) {
         console.log(err);      
      });
```

**Django RestFramework serializer**

```
from rest_framework import serializers as ser

from .models import temprorary_report_pic

class temprorary_ser(ser.ModelSerializer):    
    class Meta:
        model = temprorary_report_pic
        read_only_fields = ('Picture',)
```

**The model tied to the serializer:**

```
class temprorary_report_pic(models.Model):
Picture = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'Temprorary_report_pic/%Y/%m/%d',blank = True, null = True)   
def __unicode__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
    return '%s' %self.id
```

**The view implementing Django rest Framework's Modelviewset**

```
from .models import *
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from rest_framework.decorators import detail_route,parser_classes
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser,FileUploadParser
from rest_framework import mixins
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework import generics
from .drf_serializers import temprorary_ser
restapi_permission_classes = (AllowAny,)


class addtemprorarypicapi(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = temprorary_report_pic.objects.all()
    serializer_class = temprorary_ser 
    #permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,FormParser,FileUploadParser,)
    def perform_create(self, serializer):        
        serializer.save(Picture=self.request.data.get('file'))
```

**I have CORS Installed on django and the settings are:**

```
CORS_URLS_REGEX = '^.*$'
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
        'x-requested-with',
        'content-type',
        'accept',
        'origin',
        'authorization',
        'accept-encoding',
        'x-csrftoken'
    )
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = ( 'GET', 'POST',  'PUT',    'PATCH',    'DELETE',   'OPTIONS' )
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

**The url.py that redirects the request:**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'^addtemprorarypicapi', addtemprorarypicapi)
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)), 
    ]
```

Comment: I guess the problem was with the content-type declarations in the headers sections of the angular  i changed it to this and it worked                                                                      headers :{ Connection:"close", 'content-type':'undefined', Vary:'Accept' ,'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'x-requested-with' },